# How do I migrate an OSX Xamarin project to Visual Studio on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I'm in a situation where I've been developing in a very large Xamarin project using Xamarin Studio on OSX and I now have to migrate to Windows 10 / Visual Studio. Recreating the project is not an option, as I said it's quite large. I've searched up on the topic but I'm finding very little information on this and most comments are from several years ago. I tried opening the project in Visual Studio (2015) and get the following errors:

```
(Both reference the file "values-v24.xml")

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Borderless.Colored'
```

Has anyone successfully migrated from OSX to Windows / Vis Studio that can advise? The project targets both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Xamarin projects are fully compatible with Xamarin Studio, Visual Studio for Mac and Visual Studio for Windows. I'd recommend updating to VS2017 as this has all the latest support but otherwise it will work.

Based off your error I would check that you have the same Android SDK versions installed on Windows as you had on Mac.

Comment: Agreed. Make sure you use VS2017. Any edition will do. Make sure it's fully up to date before you transition.